# Elastic Reindex does not copy all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using the elastic reindex api at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

However, sometimes this job abruptly gives up the copying randomly and returns with completed:true status. Also, there are no running background tasks as well if we check via `_cat/tasks?v=true&detailed=true`

We take some actions when reindex is complete (making it active) however the data is not complete and causing search issues.

[image]

Usually, the expectation is that the total = created + version conflicts (we use operation type as create) when completed flag is true.

Any idea why all documents are not being copied sometimes and/or the reindexing task gives up midway with a false completed status ?

Note: This does not happen always and could be related to a slightly higher load as well.

Comment: When you reindex are you also specifying `?wait_for_completion=false`? Doing so would persist the task details in the `.tasks` index that you can investigate after the fact. Sometimes it could be a circuit breaker tripping or something else, but without persisting the task details, you would know. maybe you can also find something in the ES server logs. Can you also show the full reindex command you're running?

Comment: yes we pass that parameter. Also, found the answer to this in the logs. The disk space and flood watermark was in the logs. One of our nodes was out of space.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!